# How to direct git-lfs traffic for multiple remotes to a single endpoint?

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-lfs, bitbucket-server

I use a workstation to develop and two remotes to store: a local (LAN) git server [origin] and a hosted (e.g. bitbucket/github) git server [cloud] for extra backup.

I am currently using git lfs to track png files and my available online storage is running out. As a solution, I'd like to store png files exclusively on the origin remote. To achieve this I have attempted to configure the lfsurl for my cloud endpoint to be the same as the origin. This way, I expect that pushing a png to either git endpoint would result in the image going to the same location (and *ignored* in the cloud push?).

For a given repo here are samples of my git config files:

**.git/config**

> [remote "origin"] 
>   url = ssh://git@git.myserver.com:7999/project/repo-data.git
>   [remote "cloud"] 
>   url = git@bitbucket.org:user/repo-data.git

**.lfsconfig**

> [remote "cloud"]
>   lfsurl = https://git.myserver.com/project/repo-data.git/info/lfs

Output from git lfs env

```
$ git lfs env
Endpoint=https://git.myserver.com/project/repo-data.git/info/lfs (auth=none)
Endpoint (cloud)=https://git.myserver.com/project/repo-data.git/info/lfs (auth=none)
```

The above configuration is functional as images are pushed to git lfs. Unfortunately the images continue to be pushed to *both* remotes (origin + cloud). I expect the pointer file on the cloud remote, but no png.

I suspect my lfsurl is incorrect and git lfs is falling back to the default url for each remote, but I see no errors or warnings. Are there tools/logs to troubleshoot?

How to direct git lfs traffic for multiple remotes to a single endpoint?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Today I got the same situation, I worked it out with the following configuration.

**.lfsconfig**

```
[lfs]
        url = https://git.labs.xxxxx/test/test.git/info/lfs
```

You can refer to the [tutorial](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/wiki/Tutorial)

you should disable LFS functionality in GitLab if you use GitLab and LFS objects are not stored in the GitLab built-in LFS server, otherwise you will fail to push, refer to the [POST](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/issues/40616).